# Tagging tables/columns in Snowflake

Tags: tags, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pii

A quick question please -

Is there a good way of storing classification tags in Snowflake at table/column level? For example, tag a column with PII flag.

I then like to read these tags through JDBC API.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no built-in tagging with Snowflake. You could build the metadata yourself in your own table structure, or perhaps take advantage of [comments](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/comment.html) (Comments are a SQL ANSI standard). Depending on how you are planning on using this metadata after it's stored would determine which direction you want to go. If you wanted to obfuscate to certain users in the future, then your own metadata tables would be the way to go.

Comment: Hi, Can you please let me know how I can specify that a column is of PII type in the table structure itself without using the COMMENT keyword? I would be reading comments & the PII tags through JDBC API and store them in Collibra for Data Governance purposes. Currently, I am able to store comments. Now, PII tags are essential to protect the data through masking policies in Immuta.

Answer (score 0):

Object tagging is one of the new features announced at the Snowflake Summit in June. It is currently in Private Preview.

Comment: Hi Eda, please see my comment above. I want to define manually that a column is of PII type within the table structure itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think Currently we have only one option of using the COMMENT for such need but this is also not that much flexible.
We may need to wait for snowflake to enable the classification and tagging feature for Public preview to solve this c